# Два класса одна Activity

Tags: android, activity

Здравствуйте, у меня в приложении все данные отображаются на одном MainActivity, однако данные эти сами по себе разные (если говорить конкретнее, то это отображение показаний магнитометра и кнопки). Я хотел бы, что бы кнопки у меня остались реализованы в MainActivity.Class, а вот TextView, в которые у меня записываются показания датчика и все методы, связанные с магнитометром ушли в другой класс, например MagnetInfo. Проблема в том, что при запуске приложения у меня отрабатывает только onCreate класса MainActivity, а вот показания датчика не отображаются. Возможно ли как-то заставить все это работать?

Иными словами, возможно ли как-то инициализировать два класса, для одного Activity?

P.S. Мне кажется важным, что данные в TextView класса MagnetInfo обновляются с помощью метода onSensorChanged()
Я хочу сделать именно так для того, чтобы не перегружать класс Main

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержание проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А я бы оставил `onSensorChanged()` в `MainActivity`. Можно конечно вынести обработчик событий в отдельный класс и предавать в него контекст активити, но по моему 20 лишних строк кода не сильно перегрузят класс активити.

Comment: Мне кажется что @Plato не разделяет понятия разметки и активности. Я предполагаю, что вы создали две активности MainActivity.class и MagnetInfoActivity.class и соответственно разметки к ним activity_main.xml и activity_magnet_info.xml . Затем вы открыли разметку activity_main.xml и вставили в неё разметку magnetinfo.xml . Всю логику разделили и записали в классы. Проблема в том, что по умолчанию у вас вызывается MainActivity.class и он заполняет данные разметки activity_main.xml . А т.к. activity_magnet_info.xml является частью activity_main.xml, то заполять её будет MainActivity.class

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев Не совсем так, я действительно создал отдельный класс MagnetInfo, но для него нет отдельного Activity. Добавил скриншот структуры.

Comment: @Plato из того что я понял, вам подойдёт совет lampa. Но пока мы не видим кода из MainActivity, то это больше похоже на гадание по кофейной гуще